# Changing file extension within the file command

Tags: linux, unix, find, zip

I am using the following command to find files, zip them up and delete the original file:

```
find data/* -type f -execdir zip '{}'.zip '{}' \; -delete
```

At the moment if a file called "something.txt" is found a zip file called "something.txt.zip" is created.  How do I make the filename "something.zip" instead?

I know in bash I can do something like ${x:.*} but I cannot seem to get something like this working here.

Comment: Why would you do that? If you name it something.zip it will get called something after unzip

Comment: @hek2mgl I only want to call the zip file something.zip, the contents should stay as something.txt.

Comment: Sure the contents stay the same but you'll loose the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work but it is a bit of a fudge:

```
find data/* -execdir bash -c 'zip -j "${1%.*}.zip" "${1}"' _ {} \;
```

I would love to see something cleaner.